# Warning in Chrome when loading Pinterest pinit.js file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pinterest

Getting the following warning when trying to load Pinterest API JS code:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://widgets.pinterest.com/v3/pidgets/log/?via=http%3A%2F%2Fsamplesite…are%2F&type=pidget&callback=PIDGET_1361830898800.f.devNull&t=1361830898802".
```

Accessing the script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Also have this code:

```
$(".div5").append('<div class="pin-it"><a id="pinterest_a" data-pin-config="above" href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' + source_url + '&media=' + source_image + '&description=' + image_description + '" data-pin-do="buttonPin" ><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" /></a></div>');


    var element = document.getElementById('pinterest_a');

    try{
        (function (x) {
            for (var n in x)
                if (n.indexOf('PIN_') == 0)
                    return x[n];

            return null;
        })(window).f.render.buttonPin(element);
    }
    catch (e) {
        //catch and just suppress error
    }
```

Using Google Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a minor issue with the way Pinterest has their web service set up. You can safely ignore it.